# Finding contours from a thresholded image

Tags: python, opencv

I'm currently reading through the example code on the OpenCV website tyring to find contours in an image.

I first read an image and convert to gray-scale:

```
img = cv2.imread('/.../.../four.png')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

I then convert the image into binary by applying a threshold:

```
thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

According to the tutorials.. I should then be able to call `findContours()` on the thresholded image:

```
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

When trying to execute this code, for some reason i'm getting a type error:

> contours =
>   cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
>   **TypeError: image is not a numerical tuple**

Unsure why?

Here's the full code for easier readability:

```
img = cv2.imread('/Users/samtozer/Desktop/four.png')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
```

Wondering if anyone has experienced this problem before? And if so, what is going wrong xD

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use this : `contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`

Comment: Just tried that, still getting same err

Comment: are you able to `print contours` ?

Comment: Unfortunately not... the program is terminating on line 8 (`findContours`)

Comment: [`cv2.threshold`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold) returns a tuple, and the image is the second element... Why not read the documentation?

Comment: Yes but if I declare `thresh = cv2.threshold(src,127,255,0)` that should give `thresh` the destination source shouldn't it?

Comment: @dipper Dan Masek is right. You should replace the line of code to `ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)`. Because `cv2.threshold` returns a tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments there are two issues that you have to look out for:

**Return type of `cv2.findContours()`**

There are two return values in `cv2.findContours()`:

- Contours present in the image
- The hierarchy of these contours

**Return type of `cv2.threshold()`**

There are two return values in `cv2.threshold()`:

- Return value. (It returns `float` value of the threshold value which is used to classify the pixel values)
- Thresholded image

Comment: Might be worth to mention the info about `findContours` is valid for OpenCV 2.4.x. In OpenCV 3.x [it returns 3 values](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html).